# Eclipse DDMS window not showing any thing +android

Tags: android, emulation, ddms

my Eclipse DDms window not showing anything(empty logcat,empty file explore... etc) while running my app in emulator. Sometime it works if i restart eclipse but not all time. why such type of hanging...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even i face the same problem number of times. What i use to do is go to DDMS and click on the emulator name which is displayed in left side of the window under title "Name" in the Devices-view. Now Logcat will begin to display sequence of events. If this doesn't works then reset adb by clicking the down arrow in the left side of the DDMS window under the title "Devices". Hope this solves your problem

Comment: I reset adb but Eclipse hangs(Not responding)

Comment: @amy some time it happns to me also.. i always wait for a minute or restart

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today.  Try`Window > Reset Perspective` like this:

[image]