# DDMS perspective displays absolutely nothing eclipse 4.1

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

all I get is a light blue screen with nothing on it.

anyone ever see anything like this?

all other perspectives display normally.

thanks for any insight.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of eclipse running?

Comment: Did you try "Window -> Reset Perspectivr"?

Comment: Also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429083/eclipse-ddms-window-not-showing-any-thing-android

Answer (score 3):

You see a blank window because the DDMS view is not configured to show anything. You can configure to show them by going to:

Windows --> Show View --> Other --> Android

and select the views (for example: Emulator Control, Devices, File Explorer, etc.), and then you are ready to roll.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with ADT 23.0.2.1259578 on Windows 7, I tried resetting the perspective and also tried Windows --> Show View --> Other --> Android but that didn't work for me, Restarting Eclipse resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue . Nothing worked for me except updating eclipse.
Help-> check for updates

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This worked with the first device created and not with a second device : DDMS showing empty file explorer for online emulator.
I deleted all devices and recreated a new one and it works.
I think that only a single device can be run with debugging